# How to use unordered_map of unordered_maps in c++?

Tags: c++, data-structures, unordered-map

I have below data structures problem ? Could you please help me out.
So I my requirement is to initialise this data structures to default values when I add the new data items into this map.

How can I do this efficiently ?

I need a1, a2, a3 should be set to zero for each entry I am going to add.

```
struct a {
 int a1;
 int a2;
 int a3;
};

struct A {
 struct a A1;
 struct a A2;
};

unordered_map<int, unordered_map<int, struct A>> big_map;
```

Tried running below code.

```
    unordered_map<int, struct A> inner_map;
    big_map[0] = inner_map;
    struct A m;
    big_map[0][0] = m;
    cout << "Values: " << big_map[0][0].A1.a1 << ", " << big_map[0][0].A1.a2 << ", " << big_map[0][0].A1.a3 << endl;
```

Output:

g++ -std=c++11 -o exe b.cc
 ./exe 
Values: 0, 0, 1518395376
./exe 
Values: 0, 0, -210403408
 ./exe 
Values: 0, 0, -1537331360
./exe 
Values: 0, 0, -915603664

So default initialisation is not being done for a3 ?

Comment: @SombreroChicken No need for that, after c++11 inserting to a map leads to a default initialisation, even if the type does not have a constructor e.g. ints, floats etc.

Comment: @KostasRim That was the generalized answer, not including C++11. But then again `unordered_map` is C++11 only so you're right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a default constructor to your structs:

```
struct a {
    a() : a1(0), a2(0), a3(0) { }
    ...
};

struct A {
    A() : A1(), A2() { }
    ...
};
```

And then when you add a new struct you can do:

```
big_map[5][7] = A();
```

Comment: I did not understand why A1() ?, A1 is variable

Comment: @jpb123 `A1` is a struct object. `A1()` in the initialization list is explicitly calling its default constructor to set `a1, a2, a3` to 0.

Comment: @jpb123 Do you mean in the initialiser-list of A's constructor? It default initialises the A1 member variable.

Comment: @scohe001, Thank you so much.  I was not knowing this. It works.

Comment: @SeanBurton, A1(some_another_struct_a_variable) initializes A1 with some_another_struct_a_variable and A1() initializes A1 using default constructor. . Am I right ?

Comment: You don't need the constructor for `A` since it's a non-POD type (since `a` has a constructor) and `A1` and `A2` will be [default-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization) anyway

Answer (score 6):

Since C++11 you can do this:

```
struct a {
 int a1 = 0;
 int a2 = 0;
 int a3 = 0;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can give constructor to struct just like class, and init it to 0

```
struct a
{
   int a1;
   int a2;
   int a3;
   a() : a1(0), a2(0), a3(0)
   {
   }
}
```